# webview is not redirecting anymore (Facebook API in webos)

Tags: facebook, redirect, webview, facebook-graph-api, webos

I am trying to implement the possibility to post on your facebook wall from my app. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ web application section.

It used to work. What i did was open the following URL in a webview

"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=123456789123456&redirect_uri=http://www.mydomain.com&scope=publish_stream&display=wap"

And after the user typed his credentials and gives me the neede permissions, the webview was redirected to the redirect uri (www.mydomain.com) including a get variable from which i parsed a code which is needed.

But all of a sudden i am not redirected to the redirect_uri anymore. I am redirected to a blank facebook page (http://m.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php)

It DOES work on a PC Browser and even in the webos browser, but not in the webview.

I even wrote a complete new application with nothing but a webiveiw in it. The main-assistant.js looks like this.

```
    function MainAssistant(argFromPusher) {
}

MainAssistant.prototype = {
   setup: function() {
      Ares.setupSceneAssistant(this);
      console.log("setup");
      //this.controller.get("facetimes").mojo.clearCookies();
      //this.controller.get("facetimes").mojo.clearCache();
      this.controller.get("facetimes").mojo.openURL("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=123456789&redirect_uri=http://www.mydomain.com/callback&scope=publish_stream&display=touch");
      this.controller.listen("facetimes",Mojo.Event.webViewTitleUrlChanged,this.titleChanged.bind(this));
   },
   cleanup: function() {
      Ares.cleanupSceneAssistant(this);
   },
   titleChanged: function(event){
      console.log(event.url + " DAS IST DIE URL");
   }
};
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up the entire SDK with facebook api example on my blog

[Facebook Connect WebOS](http://blog.paschar.com/post/2011/02/08/Facebook-Connect-SDK-for-WebOS.aspx)

It's open sourced, the guide will give you the github address